# Android navigation fragment state

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

Hello i started learning android navigation. Firstly, oncreate was triggered when I called from one fragment to another and when it came back, it was not triggered when using fragment manager in the past. Am I doing something wrong? Also, when I try to use bottom navigation, the situation gets confused. I will keep the data in the viewmodel, but I need to keep even the scrollview how much it has been scrolled. Then, when you come back to the page, the view scrolls instantly.
when it works in this code if i press backspace then oncreated doesn't work again this is good
[image: this code]

but this code trigged oncreated If I press the back button in fragment2
[image]

this is my navigation
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason `onViewCreated` is called when using `FragmentManager` with the `add` method is when you `add` a `Fragment` into `FragmentManager`'s back stack, it gets added on top of the current fragment and does not destroy your current fragment, so when you press back on the new fragment since the last fragment already exists in the back stack with all of its views intact, then the `onViewCreated` do not get called!

But when you use `NavigationComponent` for navigating its API uses the `replace` method instead of the `add` method. When you add a fragment into the back stack using the `replace` method, `FragmentManager` destroys the current fragment's views and just keeps the fragment's data and then creates the new fragment and adds it to the back stack. So when you press back from the new fragment, since the last fragment's view got destroyed, then its view should get created again so the `onViewCreated` gets called :)

You can read more about how these methods work [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager).

Comment: Navigation seems to make things more difficult. isn't it   Fragment Manager Easier Way  ? If I have 10 buttons, and all text changed on click , should i put their final states in viewModel?

Comment: Well, it's better if you use `replace` instead of `add` since `add` causes your fragment's views to stay inside memory and it can impact your application's performance :).
And for your second question; yes, it is better to put them inside your `ViewModel` since it can survive configuration change and does not causes the form's data to reset to its initial state